# How can I read the same line twice from a text file?

Tags: c#

I need to check each line in a file. If it equals `"EOO"` then I will break from the loop. If not I need to process that line.

The problem is the line is being skipped

```
while (r2.ReadLine() != "EOO")//check
{
    string temp = r2.ReadLine();
    if (temp == "Customer Name: " + name + "")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to store `r2.ReadLine()` in a variable somehow.

Comment: You might have to load the string into memory and check that way.

Comment: Your problem is because you call .ReadLine() twice... call it once, store it locally then read the variable.

Answer (score 4):

Save the value in a [variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wew5ytx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and use the value saved in that variable in your following code:

```
var text = r2.ReadLine(); // read a line and save it in `text`

while (text != "EOO" && !r2.EndOfStream) // check for `EOO` or end of the file
{
    // your code, use the `text` variable instead of reading the next line
    if (text == $"Customer Name: {name}")
    {
        ...
    }

    text = r2.ReadLine(); // read the next line
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should include `null` to avoid an infinite loop if there's a file without `EOO`. I'm also missing the `"Customer Name: " + name` check.

Comment: The `EndOfStream` you used in your answer is better than checking for `null` I guess. Included the other check, thought it was obvious, but I guess it isn't to OP. Thanks @Tim

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it's value to a variable in the while loop:

```
var line = null;

while((line = r2.ReadLine()) != "EOO")
{
    //Now process line, there you have the read value.
}
```